# Mysql query optimisation - Very slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I need to optimise my query which is running very slow, but don't know how to do it. It contains a subquery which is making it very slow. If I remove the inline query then it runs very well.

The query is:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT  t.service_date, 
        t.service_time, 
        (SELECT js.modified_date FROM rej_job_status js WHERE js.booking_id=b.booking_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) `cancel_datetime`, 
        b.booking_id, 
        b.ref_booking_id, 
        b.phone, b.city, 
        b.booking_time, 
        CONCAT(rc.firstname," ",rc.lastname) customer_name, 
        rc.phone_no, 
        rs.service_id,
        rs.service_name,
        rct.city_name 
FROM rej_job_details t 
JOIN rej_booking b ON t.booking_id = b.booking_id 
JOIN rej_customer rc ON rc.customer_id = b.customer 
JOIN rej_service rs ON t.service_id = rs.service_id 
JOIN rej_city rct ON rct.city_id=b.city 
WHERE t.act_status = 0 AND DATE(b.booking_time) >= '2016-06-01' 
        AND DATE(b.booking_time) <= '2016-06-14' 
ORDER BY b.booking_time DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

The explain plan shows this:

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys       key         key_len ref                         rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY             b       ALL     PRIMARY             NULL        NULL    NULL                        32357   Using where; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY             rct     eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY     4       crmdb.b.city        1       NULL
1   PRIMARY             t       ref     booking_id          booking_id  4       crmdb.b.booking_id  1       Using where
1   PRIMARY             rs      eq_ref  PRIMARY,service_id  PRIMARY     4       crmdb.t.service_id  1       NULL
1   PRIMARY             rc      eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY     4       crmdb.b.customer    1       Using where 
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  js      index   NULL                PRIMARY     4       NULL                        1       Using where
```

a) How to read this explain plan and know what it means?

b) How can I optimize this query?

Answer (score 1):

`booking_time` is hiding inside a function, so `INDEX(booking_time)` cannot be used.  That leads to a costly table scan.

```
AND DATE(b.booking_time) >= '2016-06-01' 
AND DATE(b.booking_time) <= '2016-06-14'
```

-->

```
AND b.booking_time >= '2016-06-01' 
AND b.booking_time <  '2016-06-15' -- note 3 differences in this line
```

Or, this might be simpler (by avoiding second date calculation):

```
AND b.booking_time >= '2016-06-01' 
AND b.booking_time <  '2016-06-01' + INTREVAL 2 WEEK
```

In the `EXPLAIN`, I expect the 'ALL' to become 'range', and 'Filesort' to vanish.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the full `explain`-plan, you should read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html), but the most important information it includes is the indexes mysql uses, or, usually more revealing, which it doesn't use.

For your `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` (that is your "inline query"), it doesn't use a good index, which makes your query slow, so you need to add the index `rej_job_status(booking_id)` on your table `rej_job_status`.

Create it, test it and check your `explain` plan again, it should then list that new index under `key` for your `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`.

Another optimization might be to add an index `rej_booking(booking_time)` for your table `rej_booking`. It depends on your data if it improves the query, but you should try it, since right now, mysql doesn't use an index for that selection.